# jQuery element somehow cached in setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to trigger a click on an element every x seconds. It's not the exact same element every time (depending on which tab a user has selected, it should click that tab), but they are all in the same container (with id `#container`. The selected element has the class `.selected` and gets that class when it has been clicked on by a user.

This is the code I have:

```
var feedContainer = $('#container');
window.setInterval(function () {
    var selectedTab = feedContainer.find('.selected');
    selectedTab.trigger('click');
}, 10000);
```

The problem is that between the timeouts, if a user clicks on another tab, this part doesn't pick up on that: `var selectedTab = feedContainer.find('.selected');`. It just gets the one that was selected before, not the new one that has the class. How do I avoid that?

It works fine if I do the entire selection in the timer each time (`var selectedTab = $('#container .selected');`). It seems to be somehow caching the results from the last run.

Why is this and how do I force it to fetch the correct element?

Comment: What is the problem with using _var selectedTab = $('#container .selected')_ instead of _var selectedTab = feedContainer.find('.selected');_ ?

Comment: @Sidd my thoughts exactly!

Comment: I don't have to go back to the DOM to fetch the container multiple times --> performance gain.

Comment: You have to go back, since you want it to find the latest selected element every time. It's good to use caching and performance benefits when you don't need to requery, but clearly in this case you do - that's the very issue you are posting about. Can't have cake and eat too, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already caching the element yourself by doing this:

```
var feedContainer = $('#container');
```

If the contents change after you assign it to the variable then that variable won't get updated with the new contents automagically.

---

Just use it like this `$('#container');` directly whenever you want to do operations on it.

Comment: As stated in the question I know it works when done like that, I just wanted to take advantage of that cashed element and not have to go back to the DOM to get the same, wrapping element multiple times. And I thought all I get is a reference to that DOM element, and that the reference (and the content) is updated when the DOM is

Comment: well, you learned the hard-way that it's not - You are storing the DOM node within the variable

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is that in the beginning, you gather some elements that match the selection (using `$('#container')`) but later on, you change the content of `#container` which is not reflected in the jQuery object in `feedContainer`. Simply get the container on each iteration.

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    var feedContainer = $('#container');

    var selectedTab = feedContainer.find('.selected');
    selectedTab.trigger('click');
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    var selectedTab = $('#container').find('.selected');
    selectedTab.trigger('click'); 
}, 10000);
```

As container is not changed above is proposed.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, an ID should ideally be used to identify a "single" element, not multiple elements. Changing that would help you out by spreading the elements with the same name using a "class" identifier. Changing that might help you out a lot.

Answer (score -1):

I'd do it like this.  Short, to the point and no variable assigning thus no caching.

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    $('#container .selected').trigger('click');
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Why did I get minus? Please comment. Is there anything wrong??

Comment: It's a redundant answer

Comment: I don't think so. The problem with caching was explained. Fetching the correct element was explained. And even the question 'How do I avoid that?' Was answered...